# Две окружности с кружочками-табами, js

Tags: javascript

Есть две окружности с кружочками, и при нажатии на них должна появляться информация, по сути те же самые табы/вкладки, при этом ещё нужно чтобы менялся цвет кружочков. В итоге я остановился на том, что мне нужно поменять цвет моих активных и неактивных дуг, чтобы активная была красного цвета, а не активная - черного. Получилось только ( и то криво), сделать активные красными, а как тогда сделать чтобы они ещё и чернели? :/ Код выглядит сыро, решил писать в отдельном html файле-черновике, а не сразу на сайт.

```js
const services__btn = document.querySelectorAll(".circle__point");
        const services__tab_content = document.querySelectorAll(
            ".circle__point_txt"
        );

        services__btn.forEach((tab, i) => {
            tab.addEventListener("click", () => {
                services__btn.forEach((tab) => {
                    tab.classList.remove("active");
                });
                tab.classList.add("active");

                services__tab_content.forEach((content) => {
                    content.classList.remove("active");
                });
                services__tab_content[i].classList.add("active");
            });
        });

        const services__btn_color = document.querySelectorAll(".circle__point_color");
        const services__tab_content_color = document.querySelectorAll(
            ".circle_color"
        );

        services__btn_color.forEach((tab, i) => {
            tab.addEventListener("click", () => {
                services__tab_content_color.forEach((content1) => {
                    content1.classList.remove("active_cir");
                });
                services__tab_content_color[i].classList.add("active_cir");
            });
        });
```

```css
.circle_animation {
            margin: 160px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .circle_one {
            transform: rotate(135deg);
            width: 440px;
            height: 440px;
        }

        .circle_one_one {
            width: 440px;
            height: 220px;
            border-radius: 220px 220px 0 0;
            border-top: 3px solid black;
            border-left: 3px solid black;
            border-right: 3px solid black;
        }

        .circle_one_two {
            width: 440px;
            height: 220px;
            /* margin: -0.5px 0 0 0; */
            border-radius: 0 0 220px 220px;
            border-bottom: 3px solid red;
            border-left: 3px solid red;
            border-right: 3px solid red;
        }

        .circle_one_one__point {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: aqua;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            top: 2px;
            left: -5px;
        }

        .circle_two {
            transform: rotate(315deg);
            position: absolute;
            top: -50px;
            left: -50px;
            width: 540px;
            height: 540px;
        }

        .circle_two_one {
            width: 540px;
            height: 270px;
            border-radius: 270px 270px 0 0;
            border-top: 3px solid black;
            border-left: 3px solid black;
            border-right: 3px solid black;
        }

        .circle_two_two {
            width: 540px;
            height: 270px;
            margin: -0.5px 0 0 0;
            border-radius: 0 0 270px 270px;
            border-bottom: 3px solid red;
            border-left: 3px solid red;
            border-right: 3px solid red;
        }

        .circle_two_one__point {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: aqua;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            top: 250px;
            left: 48px;
            z-index: 999;
        }

        .circle_tree {
            transform: rotate(27deg);
            position: absolute;
            top: -100px;
            left: -100px;
            width: 640px;
            height: 640px;
        }

        .circle_tree_one {
            width: 640px;
            height: 320px;
            border-radius: 320px 320px 0 0;
            border-top: 3px solid black;
            border-left: 3px solid black;
            border-right: 3px solid black;
        }

        .circle_tree_two {
            width: 640px;
            height: 320px;
            margin: -0.5px 0 0 0;
            border-radius: 0 0 320px 320px;
            border-bottom: 3px solid red;
            border-left: 3px solid red;
            border-right: 3px solid red;
        }

        .circle_tree_one__point {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: aqua;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            top: 520px;
            left: 70px;
            z-index: 999;
        }

        .circle_tree_two__point {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: aqua;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            top: 55px;
            left: 501px;
            z-index: 999;
        }

        .circle__point_txt {
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 50px;
            display: none;
        }

        .circle_info {
            position: absolute;
            top: 200px;
            left: 160px;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        .circle__point_txt.active {
            display: block;
        }

        .circle__point_txt.active~.point2 {
            display: block;
        }

        #Services__tab_1:checked~[for='Services__tab_1'],
        #Services__tab_2:checked~[for='Services__tab_2'],
        #Services__tab_3:checked~[for='Services__tab_3'] {
            background-color: #5ccd6a;
            color: white;
        }

        input {
            display: none;
        }

        .active_cir {
            /* border-bottom: 0.3px solid red; */
            border-top: 3px solid red;
            border-left: 3px solid red;
            border-right: 3px solid red;
        }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <!-- <div style="width: 400px;height: 400px;">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
            <canvas id="canvas2" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
        </div> -->
        <div class="circle_animation">
            <div class="circle_info">
                <span>INFORMATION</span>
            </div>
            <div class="circle_one">
                <div class="circle_one_one"></div>
                <div class="circle_one_two"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle_two">
                <div class="circle_two_one circle_color">
                    <div class="circle__point_txt">span2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="circle_two_two"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle_tree">
                <div class="circle_tree_one circle_color">
                    <input type="radio" name="Services" id="Services__tab_1">
                    <input type="radio" name="Services" id="Services__tab_2" checked>
                    <input type="radio" name="Services" id="Services__tab_3">
                    <label for="Services__tab_1" class="circle_two_one__point circle__point circle__point_color"></label>
                    <label for="Services__tab_2" class="circle_tree_one__point circle__point circle__point_color_cir"></label>
                    <label for="Services__tab_3" class="circle_tree_two__point circle__point circle__point_color"></label>
                    <div class="point2 circle__point_txt active">span1</div>
                    <div class="circle__point_txt">span3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="circle_tree_two circle_color"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а если немного укорочу и ваще без js сделаю, ничо?)))

```css
.x{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
margin: 5px;
padding: 15px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 100%;
}

input{
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 20%;
z-index: 1;
}

:checked + div{border-color: red;}

#r1:checked + div{--abc: '1'}
#r2:checked + div{--abc: '2'}
#r3:checked + div{--abc: '3'}
#r4:checked + div{--abc: '4'}

:checked + div:after{
content:var(--abc);
position: absolute;
border: 3px solid blue;
border-radius: 100%;
padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='x' style='border: none;'>
<input id='r1' type='radio' name='abc'><div class='x y'>
<input id='r2' type='radio' name='abc'><div class='x y'>
<input id='r3' type='radio' name='abc'><div class='x y'>
<input id='r4' type='radio' name='abc'><div class='x y'>

<div style='height: 50px; width: 50px'>круг<br>ляшо<br>чек</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

правда расположение инпутов придется таки вручную подгонять...

Comment: Вы подсказали мне идею) Я подумал, что анимации связаны с полукругами, просто у меня круг сложен из двух полукругов, а вы решили сделать анимацию сразу на весь круг, в общем оставлю как у меня, то есть активная анимация будет сразу на весь круг, если она попадает на кружочки, которые там находятся.